# build issue with make_tuple - arrary reference

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, tuples, pass-by-reference

I've a class which takes a reference to an array of size 5 as one of the parameter in the constructor.

```
class sha1 {
public:
    typedef unsigned int(&type)[5];
    type digest_;
    sha1(const type digest) : digest_(digest)
    {}
};
```

I am able to instantiate this class by passing an array of 5. But replacing that with a call to std::make_tuple fails to compile.

```
int main(int argc, const char* const argv[]) {
    unsigned int digest[5] = { 0 };
    const sha1 s(digest);
    const sha1 p = std::make_tuple(digest);   <-- error here
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::tuple<unsigned int *>' to 'sha1'
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

How can I make this work? Code here has been simplified a lot to make it easier to explain. What I am trying to do is to use the class as a key to ***unordered_map*** and use ***emplace*** to insert entries, which gives the same error.

I am using Visual Studio 2015

Here is the code with unordered_map

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class sha1 {
public:
    typedef unsigned int(&type)[5];
    const type digest_;
    const int index_;
    sha1(const type digest, int index) : digest_(digest), index_(index)
    {}
    bool operator==(const sha1& that) const {
        return true;
    }
};

namespace std {
    template<> struct hash<sha1> {
        inline size_t operator()(const sha1& p) const {
            return 0;
        }
    };
}

int main(int argc, const char* const argv[]) {
    unsigned int digest[5] = { 0 };

    const sha1 s(digest, 10); // works

    std::unordered_map<sha1, std::string> map;

    map.insert(std::make_pair(sha1(digest, 10), "test")); // works

    map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::make_tuple(digest, 10), std::make_tuple("test"));  // <-- error here

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you try `std::tie` instead of `std::make_tuple` ?

Comment: BTW, you class doesn't take `std::tuple` as constructor...

Comment: What is your declaration for `unordered_map`?  My be you have 2 different issues.

Comment: @Steephen I've added the example that uses unordered_map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`make_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) will [`decay`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay) the arguments you pass to it before constructing the `tuple`, so the `unsigned int(&)[5]` type is converted to `unsigned int *`, which does not match your `sha1` constructor's parameter type.

Use [`forward_as_tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) instead to create a tuple of references.

```
map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(digest, 10),
            std::forward_as_tuple("test"));
```

Comment: That helped. Apart from the deay, are there any diff between make_tuple and forward_as_tuple? Are there any reasons to use make_tuple? afaik forward_as_tuple should work all the time?

Comment: @Shankaran As I said in the answer, `forward_as_tuple` creates a tuple of references, while `make_tuple` will copy/move arguments. So your question is a bit like asking "*why would I want to use `T`, shouldn't `T&` work all the time?*"